# Issues with figure that doesn't show

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
                  wind speed - Km/Hr             Wind Dir  counts    Frequency
    0                         0 - <2                    E    1278    0.018459
    1                         0 - <2                  ENE    1889    0.027284
    2                         0 - <2                  ESE    1057    0.015267
    3                         0 - <2                    N    1600    0.023110
    4                         0 - <2                   NE    2172    0.031371
.............                 ......                  ...    ....    ........
```

I want to plot a wind rose so i wrote this code:

Original code: https://plotly.com/python/wind-rose-charts/#wind-rose-chart-with-plotly-express

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="Frequency", theta="Wind Dir",
                   color="wind speed - Km/Hr", template="plotly_dark",
                   color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.show()
```

And when i run the code the figure is not shown, but a variable called fig is created. So i right click in the variable (in spyder console) and i click in the option "view with the object explorer" but the figure does not appear anyways.

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always export it, e.g. with fig.savefig('windrose.png')

Comment: @Krzysztofik i got this error message: AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'savefig'

Comment: @Krzysztofik this is the type of variable: graph_objs._figure.Figure

Comment: My bad, I had matplotlib in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you ran it under something like Jupyter. But since it Spyder, depends if you want it as a static image or interactive. But you need to look at/use renderers. For example, you can open in the browser as an html file and keep the interactive/hover parts:

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame([['0 - <2','E',1278,0.018459],
['0 - <2','ENE',1889,0.027284],
['0 - <2','ESE',1057,0.015267],
['0 - <2','N',1600,0.023110],
['0 - <2','NE',2172,0.031371]],columns = ['wind speed - Km/Hr','Wind Dir','counts','Frequency'])


import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar_polar(df, r="Frequency", theta="Wind Dir",
                   color="wind speed - Km/Hr", template="plotly_dark",
                   color_discrete_sequence= px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r)
fig.write_html("C:/test/file.html")
```

**Output:**

[image]